# Laravel - Method link_to_route does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I get an error when i use HTML::link_to_route, but not when i use HTML::Link
Why?

```php
{{ HTML::decode(HTML::link_to_route('homepage', '<div class="logo"></div>')) }}
```

The same for:

```php
{{ HTML::link_to_route('about', 'WHAT IS IT') }}
```

The error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method link_to_route does not exist.
```

Version 4.0.x

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Fixed it, it seems that the documentation is really out-dated,
or that laravel 4.0 is just really new ;)

replaced "link_to_route" with "linkRoute". Found it by looking into the vendor files.

Comment: Can I ask which documentation you were reading? There isn't any documentation for L4 on the HTML builders methods. And all methods are now camel cased, not snake cased.

Comment: This also fixed something I was reading that gave an example of using HTML::route. HTML::linkRoute works for that.

Comment: Almost a year has passed, time to update this answer ;)
The proper way to do links is:
URL::route('route-name')    and  URL::to('...')

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI, or next searcher

For the latest Release (4.1) the text will be encoded itself. to get the link you have to specify the link manually like this

```
 <a href="{{ URL::route('homepage') }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's must easier to use linkRoute.

Example: 
    {{ HTML::linkRoute('name-of-route', 'Go to my route') }}

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the old way
http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

However this seems to be the new way

```
string linkRoute(string $name, string $title = null, array $parameters = array(), array $attributes = array())
```

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.html#method_link

See usage
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/190/generating-a-html-link-to-a-named-route