# Laravel 4 named route routes properly but contents from view not displayed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been struggling with this issue for last two days. Finally decided to post my problem:

routes.php

```
Route::get('authors/newAuthors', array('as'=>'new', 'uses'=> 'authors@newAuthors'));
```

Controller (authors.php)

```
public function newAuthors(){
    $value = View::make('authors.newAuthors')
            ->with('title', 'authors Adding Page');
    return $value;
}
```

index.blade.php (In this view, I have a link to that named route "New authors")

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<h2>Authors page from index blade php</h2>
    <ul>

    @foreach($authors as $author)
        <li>{{ HTML::linkRoute('author', $author->name, `array($author['id'])) }}</li>`
    @endforeach

    </ul>
    {{ HTML::linkRoute('new', 'New Authors') }}
@stop
```

view that should be displayed after a click (newAuthors.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<h2>Add New Authors</h2>

@stop
```

When I click on the link ("New Authors"), on the URL it shows me that it is routing to the correct path:

```
http://localhost:8000/authors/newAuthors
```

But it does not display any contest from that view file (newAuthors.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I solved the problem. I found a similar problem but not exactly in here

[Routed Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467677/laravel-overrides-named-route-and-takes-wrong-one?rq=1)

All I did is shifted my this particular route that I was having problem with at the top of anything, than it started displaying me the right view. Nothing got broken though. I am not sure how it happened but I have the following routes that works as of now:

```
Route::get('authors/newAuthors', array('as'=>'new', 'uses'=> 'authors@newAuthors'));

Route::get('authors', array('as' => 'authors', 'uses' => 'authors@index'));
Route::get('authors/{id}', array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=> 'authors@viewAuthors'));
```

Even though I don't have any URI that matches exactly. Anyway, I wrote it thinking any future visitors might find it helpful and do not have to struggle like me for two days :(

Answer (score 0):

Your file blade is: 'index.blade.php'

so you need point your layout to this file: (if the index is within a subfolder use subfolder/index)

```
$value = View::make('index')
        ->with('title', 'authors Adding Page');
```

then in your route.php add a route:

```
Route::get('authors/newauthors/', array('as' => 'newAuthors', 'uses' => 'AuthorsController@newAuthors'));
```

use it in your view

```
{{link_to_route('newAuthors', 'New Authors', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())}}
```

Comment: link_to_route()... method does not exist anymore in laravel 4. Follow the link::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845540/laravel-method-link-to-route-does-not-exist

Comment: You're right SHANKAR. It was just an example for named routes.